# scrollTop not working correctly with .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Div containing overflow text that I would like to scroll through with the click of a corresponding button. It's set to scroll 100 pixels in either direction. The function works fine when I use it don't use jQuery .animate.

```
$(function() {
   $( "#upBtn" ).click(function(){
    $('#scroll').scrollTop($('#scroll').scrollTop()-100);
}); 

 $( "#downBtn" ).click(function(){
    $('#scroll').scrollTop($('#scroll').scrollTop()+100);
});
```

But once I add .animate, I can only click the button once in either direction. It won't let me scroll down past the first 100 pixels.

```
 $("#scroll").animate({ scrollTop: "100px" });
```

Any suggestions? [I put together a codepen.](http://codepen.io/alanc242/pen/kXjLqG/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is correct behavior!

Why?

Because that is already at 100px so it doesn't scroll further than that.

What should be done:

You can get the current scroll top position and add 100px to it. Like below:

```
 $("#scroll").animate({ scrollTop:  $("#scroll").scrollTop() + 100 });
```

And same goes for other way up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your explanation makes perfect sense I tried this, but clicking the Down button a second time now scrolls to the end of the text inside the DIV without any animation. The up button also works, but without animation. [Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/alanc242/pen/GqBAjp)